# Trigger `PHP` file using JS

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 3 files, one HTML, PHP and JS. I have a button in HTML and I want to trigger the PHP file when it's clicked, through Javascript. I tried the following code, but for some reason it gives me the error message every time:

JavaScript

```js
function getOutput() {
    getRequest(
        'create_json.php', // URL for the PHP file
         drawOutput,  // handle successful request
         drawError    // handle error
    );
    return false;
  }  
  // handles drawing an error message
  function drawError() {
      var container = document.getElementById('output');
      container.innerHTML = 'Bummer: there was an error!';
  }
  // handles the response, adds the html
  function drawOutput(responseText) {
      var container = document.getElementById('output');
      container.innerHTML = responseText;
  }
  // helper function for cross-browser request object
  function getRequest(url, success, error) {
      var req = false;
      try{
          // most browsers
          req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } catch (e){
          // IE
          try{
              req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
          } catch(e) {
              // try an older version
              try{
                  req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              } catch(e) {
                  return false;
              }
          }
      }
      if (!req) return false;
      if (typeof success != 'function') success = function () {};
      if (typeof error!= 'function') error = function () {};
      req.onreadystatechange = function(){
          if(req.readyState == 4) {
              return req.status === 200 ? 
                  success(req.responseText) : error(req.status);
          }
      }
      req.open("GET", url, true);
      req.send(null);
      return req;
  }
```

```html
<button id="submit" onclick="getOutput()">Submit</button>
<div id="output">waiting for action</div>
```

```
<?php
function get_data(){
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "openingpage");
$query="SELECT * FROM created_list ";
$result=mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$list_data=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $list_data[]=array(
    'ModelID'   => $row["ModelID"],
    'ImageID'   => $row["ImageID"],
    'ListID'    => $row["ListID"]
   );
}
return json_encode($list_data);
}

$file_name=date('d-m-Y').'.json';
if(file_put_contents($file_name,get_data())){
echo $file_name.' file created';    
}
else{
echo 'There is some error';
}
?>
```

I'm always getting the "Bummer: there was an error!" message. Why can't I get it . I checked the code more than 100x times but can't find whats going wrong in this code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the browser's console say? What type of result do you get when you try the URL for the PHP file in your browser?

Comment: @MrGlass  If just opened through URL It showes me the code sample of the php file. But on localhost is works like a charm, getting the mysql data and creating json file

Comment: If your browser is showing you the PHP code instead of executing it then you need to figure out why that is happening. Does the server have PHP installed, etc.

Comment: _"If just opened through URL It showes me the code sample of the php file"_ - Do you mean that you see the PHP-code? Then it's your web server configuration, not the code, that's the issue.

Comment: Put a condition of success and failure in the getOutput function and on the basis of success and failure call those two functions . Here both functions are getting called one by one . Just for testing call the drawError first and then drawOutput and check the result .

Comment: Just two nitpicks: Don't use `select *` in code, as that may break unexpectedly if you change the table structure. And use a good root password, even in mysql!

Comment: Damnn, It was really just the web server config, Idk why my localhost did that, but after I relaunched uwamp, the whole code working nicely. Thank you all for the help! And sorry for taking your time with that stupid thing.